# "for situation" or "in situation"?

Tags: meaning

I am learning this [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-28), which says

```
For 8-bit (bytes) patterns: 

Matches any decimal digit; this is equivalent to [0-9].
```

I would like to express a similar meaning by saying

> a is equivalent to b in some situation

is this an appropriate expression?

should I say

> a is equivalent to b for some situation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly what you are trying to say is not clear, but I'll do my best.
Yes. 
Normally, you will use "in" along with the word "situation" or similar word "case."

> A is equivalent to B in cases where there is no external effect.

or

> A is equivalent to B in situations arising from conflicts in...

We can use the word "for" when A and B are individually used **for** something.

> The variables A and B are equivalent for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This is a description of the *special sequence* **\d** in *regular expression* syntax. When the regular expression is acting on bytes, this sequence is equivalent to **[0-9]** which is another special sequence.

You could say

> **\d** is equivalent to **[0-9]** for byte patterns. For Unicode patterns, **\d** matches additional characters that are also considered digits.